# Bootstrap 4 collapsing two navbars into one toggle button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to apply this [Bootstrap 4.0 - Two NavBars that collapse into one toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736517/bootstrap-4-0-two-navbars-that-collapse-into-one-toggle) answer to my issue but am not resolving it after some effort.

I'm trying to have the content of both navbars collapse into one toggle button.

The two issues are **once collapsed to sm** my toggle button doesn't display its content (from either target), and that at sm width my lower navbar does not maintain it's height. My code:

```html
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target1, #collapse_target2">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse_target1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <a class="navbar-brand">
                        <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/businessman-shouting-through-megaphone_23-2147511376.jpg" style="height: 2em">
                        <span>Home</span>
                    </a>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse_target2">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 6</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 7</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a single class to data-target the Navbars, instead of different id's. For example, give both the navbar-collapse elements the `navbars` class, and then the target is `data-target=".navbars"`.

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/PvHpcBNuAp

<strike>Also, I'm not sure why you're using `sticky-top` on the 1st navbar. You should remove that otherwise the 2nd navbar will slide under the first on mobile when scrolling.</strike> If you want both navbars fixed at the top, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417018/bootstrap-4-multiple-fixed-top-navbars).

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbars">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbars" id="collapse_target1">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
                <a class="navbar-brand">
                    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/businessman-shouting-through-megaphone_23-2147511376.jpg" style="height: 2em">
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbars" id="collapse_target2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 6</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 7</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

---

Also see: [Bootstrap 4 navbar with 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635126/bootstrap-4-navbar-with-2-rows/42635243)

Answer (score 1):

To control more than one navbar with one toggler **use a class instead of an id for the `data-target` attribute**. In the example below I used the class `navbar1and2`.

To maintain the height of the second navbar the same as in the uncollapsed state you can add `style="min-height: 56px"` to that navbar.

Click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page for testing:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar1and2" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar1and2" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/businessman-shouting-through-megaphone_23-2147511376.jpg" style="height: 2em">
                <span>Home</span>
            </a>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light" style="min-height: 56px">

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar1and2" id="navbarSupportedContent2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 6</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 7</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```