# Bootstrap 4 navbar with topmenu

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-4

I have a client with a 140x140 logo, the size of the logo may not be adjusted. To avoid a lot of whitespace in the header, I want to have two navbars:

- Topmenu, with a link to the login page or, if the user is already logged in, a 'Logged in as'-message. In a 80% font-size
- Regular menu

I have already found a solution on Stack Overflow: [Bootstrap 4 navbar with 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635126/bootstrap-4-navbar-with-2-rows)

But I like to position the topmenu to the right-top corner, and the regular menu to the right-bottom corner. In the solution above the navbars both got centered on the y-axis.

Is there a build-in solution for this case? Or do I have to use absolute positioning?

Comment: Use the answer in the other question to understand how alignment works and then attempt it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it in Bootstrap 4:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
           <img src="https://picsum.photos/140/" width="140" height="140" alt="Logo">
       </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column align-items-end" id="navbarCollapse">
            <!-- navbar1 -->
            <div class="navbar-nav mb-lg-5" style="font-size: 80%;">
                <span class="navbar-text">Logged in as:</span>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">User</a>
                <!-- <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Login</a> -->
            </div>

            <!-- navbar2 -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav mt-4">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Free Cookies</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```