# Bootstrap 4 navbar with 2 rows and inline form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, navbar

Ok so there are a number of questions like this but after having experimented with the code in some of the answers given to other similar questions, I'm still stuck!

I've managed to get 2 flex rows working in a flex column, with the brand image vertically centered, but I'm having trouble with the horizontal spacing.

On the first row of my navbar I have a list of nav-items and also an inline form with a search bar. I want the search bar to be right aligned, while the nav-items stay left aligned.

I've tried using justify-content-between on various elements but with no luck and I've also tried m*-auto classes but I just can't keep the nav-items and search bar on the same row while separating them horizontally!

#### Here's my code

```css
.navbar {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  /*  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);  */
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar-dark {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 45, 165, 0.97), rgba(10, 88, 157, 0.97), rgba(10, 88, 157, 0.97), rgba(0, 45, 165, 0.97));
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav-item {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding: 0 .4rem;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  transition: all .05s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#search-bar {
  background-color: #5c87af;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all .2s;
  border: none;
}

#search-bar:hover {
  background-color: #779ec1;
}

#search-bar:focus {
  background-color: white;
  color: #212529;
  width: 400px;
}

#search-bar::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white !important;
}

#search-bar:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: white !important;
}

#search-bar::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: white !important;
}

#search-bar:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/images/MW-logo-white.png" height=28 class="" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column align-items-start" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav my-1">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#property-tab">PROPERTY</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#units-tab">UNITS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tenancies-tab">TENANCIES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#pdfs-tab">PDFs</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#contacts-tab">CONTACTS</a>
      </li>
      <form class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control search" type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" />
      </form>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav my-1">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">ALL</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">CURRENT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">PAST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. Sorry I can't accept them all! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure both `navbar-nav` are full width. You can use `w-100` for this...

https://www.codeply.com/go/DGmjwI79yy

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x30" height=28 class="" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav my-1 w-100">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#property-tab">PROPERTY</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#units-tab">UNITS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tenancies-tab">TENANCIES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#pdfs-tab">PDFs</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#contacts-tab">CONTACTS</a>
      </li>
      <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
        <input class="form-control search" type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" />
      </form>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav my-1 w-100">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">ALL</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">CURRENT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">PAST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Then the `ml-auto` will work as expected to push the form right.

---

Related question:
[Bootstrap 4 navbar with 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635126/bootstrap-4-navbar-with-2-rows/42635243)

Comment: Aha it was the w-100 that I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this layout with only two `class`.

> 1 - Add `w-100` here `<ul class="navbar-nav nav my-1">`
>
> 2 - Add `ml-auto` here `<form class="form-inline">`

**Here is the working Demo**

```css
.navbar {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  /*  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);  */
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar-dark {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 45, 165, 0.97), rgba(10, 88, 157, 0.97), rgba(10, 88, 157, 0.97), rgba(0, 45, 165, 0.97));
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav-item {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding: 0 .4rem;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  transition: all .05s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#search-bar {
  background-color: #5c87af;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all .2s;
  border: none;
}

#search-bar:hover {
  background-color: #779ec1;
}

#search-bar:focus {
  background-color: white;
  color: #212529;
  width: 400px;
}

#search-bar::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white !important;
}

#search-bar:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: white !important;
}

#search-bar::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: white !important;
}

#search-bar:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/images/MW-logo-white.png" height=28 class="" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column align-items-start" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav my-1 w-100">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#property-tab">PROPERTY</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#units-tab">UNITS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tenancies-tab">TENANCIES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#pdfs-tab">PDFs</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#contacts-tab">CONTACTS</a>
      </li>
      <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
        <input class="form-control search" type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" />
      </form>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav my-1">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">ALL</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">CURRENT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">PAST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use  `ml-auto` to your search bar class.

Basically Ml is coming under **Auto Margins**
Another thing which can be applied to single flex items are margins. The following margin classes are available:

**mr-auto:** add margin to the right side of the item

**ml-auto:** add margin to the left side of the item

**mt-auto:** add margin to the top of the item

**mb-auto:** add margin to the bottom of the item

Here is your code snippet

```css
.navbar {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  /*  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);  */
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar-dark {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 45, 165, 0.97), rgba(10, 88, 157, 0.97), rgba(10, 88, 157, 0.97), rgba(0, 45, 165, 0.97));
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav-item {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding: 0 .4rem;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  transition: all .05s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#search-bar {
  background-color: #5c87af;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all .2s;
  border: none;
}

#search-bar:hover {
  background-color: #779ec1;
}

#search-bar:focus {
  background-color: white;
  color: #212529;
  width: 400px;
}

#search-bar::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white !important;
}

#search-bar:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: white !important;
}

#search-bar::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: white !important;
}

#search-bar:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/images/MW-logo-white.png" height=28 class="" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column align-items-start" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav my-1 w-100">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#property-tab">PROPERTY</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#units-tab">UNITS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tenancies-tab">TENANCIES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#pdfs-tab">PDFs</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#contacts-tab">CONTACTS</a>
      </li>
      <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
        <input class="form-control search" type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" />
      </form>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav my-1">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">ALL</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">CURRENT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">PAST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```