# How can I have Brand and Navbar on separate lines?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

Pretty simple, but I'm fairly amateur with Bootstrap.

I understand how to make the navigation bar with an image as the brand and the nav-items. Without hacking it, is there a proper way to have the brand positioned above the expanded navigation?

Basically looking for this;

```
EXPANDED
-----------------------------------------
|                 Logo                  |
-----------------------------------------
|         Home   About   Contact        |
-----------------------------------------

COLLAPSED
-----------------
| Logo        ≡ |
-----------------
```

```
<nav class="mainNav navbar navbar-expand-md justify-content-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" height="80px" width="auto">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just as an extra question ... I've tried googling this with no clear results. What search query would you use to find this answer (future reference)?

Comment: *"center navbar items bootstrap v4*" or *"center logo navbar bootstrap v4"* would likely yield enough to fix your issue without problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flex-column` to make the navbar items stack in 2 rows (lines).

- group the logo & toggler together in 1 flexbox div (`d-flex w-100`)
- use `mx-md-auto` (auto-margins) to center the logo on larger widths
- use `text-center` to center items in the `navbar-nav`

https://www.codeply.com/go/W9HQcd3Pyw

```
<nav class="mainNav navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light flex-column">
    <div class="w-100 d-flex">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-md-auto" href="#">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" height="80px" width="auto">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Read more about the [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) and [Utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) classes in the Bootstrap 4 docs.

---

**Related questions**
[How to centre navbar logo in Boostrap 4 with nav-links below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554977/how-to-centre-navbar-logo-in-boostrap-4-with-nav-links-below)
[Bootstrap 4: Navbar with logo and 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999447/bootstrap-4-navbar-with-logo-and-2-rows)
[Bootstrap 4 navbar with 2 rows and inline form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275317/bootstrap-4-navbar-with-2-rows-and-inline-form)

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified to have both the logo and the navbar centered.

Comment: That works much better. The only issue is that the toggler stretches the whole height of it's parent because of the d-flex class. I've been playing around with it for about 40 mins, just can't get it to be square (and aligned vertically in the center of it's parent). Any ideas?

Comment: Got it. Line 2
   <div class="w-100 d-flex align-items-center"> -- Thank you so much !