# How move 'nav' element under 'navbar-brand' in my Navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, navbar

I using Bootstrap 4 and I set `navbar-brand` to the center and all elements to the right side. I want to set my `nav` element below `navbar-brand`. [image]

Also, I want to set "login" and "log out" to the right side of the `nav`, but using `mr-auto` doesn't work.

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Academind</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
    <ul class="navbar-nav  ">
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Users</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Products</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav  mr-auto ">
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Log out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To right align the login, you'd use `ml-auto` to auto fill the *left* side, which will push the links to the *right*.

[image]

**Option 1:**

Then adjust the `min-height` of the navbar. Use `align-items-end` to push the links to the bottom, and align the brand on top as desired. This will give the appearance of 2 Navbar rows.

```
@media (min-width: 567px) {
    .navbar-brand
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    .navbar {
        min-height: 90px;
    }
}  

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Academind</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse align-self-end" id="navbarMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Users</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Products</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Log out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/07ibCvkQJi

**Option 2: (remove extra CSS)**

Simply apply `flex-column` to the `navbar`, and wrap the brand and toggler together in one flexbox div. Use the auto margin utils to center the brand.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark flex-column align-items-stretch">
    <div class="d-flex">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mx-sm-auto mr-auto">Academind</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="navbarMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Users</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Products</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/qVJPhAy6fS

---

Related:
[How can I have Brand and Navbar on separate lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780918/how-can-i-have-brand-and-navbar-on-separate-lines)

Answer (score 1):

you can use bootstrap4 class `d-flex`, without any extra CSS:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="w-100 d-flex flex-column">

    <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Academind</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">

        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Users</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Products</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="navbar-nav  ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div></nav>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/PouyaAk/1m2pLn9j/18/