# React-Bootstrap Navbar with 2 rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, next.js

I am looking for 2 rows of of Navbars using React-Bootstrap, similar to this posted sometime ago in Stackflow, [Bootstrap 4 navbar with 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635126/bootstrap-4-navbar-with-2-rows). I have tried out all my options and it is not working. Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong.
Below is my code.

........

```
const Header = () => {
 return (
 <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
 <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
 <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
 <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">

 <Nav className="mr-auto">
    <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
    <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
    <NavDropdown.Divider />
    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>
 </Nav>
  <Form inline>
    <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
    <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
  </Form>
  <span className ="Nav">     
  <Nav className="justify-content-center">
      <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#home">Product</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#home">Solutions</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#home">Resources</Nav.Link>
  </Nav>    
  </span>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
  )}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar issue, so I tried to change the default CSS property of Navbar and I found that `flex-flow: column` will work nicely.

Note that you must overwrite the default CSS of your navbar!

Another approach is to wrap your Navbar in a div element, something like this:

```
<div className="header">
        <div className="row-1">
            Row 1 contetnt
        </div>
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="md">
            Row 2 content
        </Navbar>
</div>
```