# Can I have one logo that spans over two navbars in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, nav

I'm developing a theme for a custom wordpress site, and currently building out a three row navbar.

I'm wondering, is it possible to "combine" the top two navbars so that I can have one logo span the height of the two combined navbars, while still maintaining the separation of list items?

This question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112363/bootstrap-navbar-with-two-rows) for Bootstrap v3, but I'm having a hard time mapping the solution over to Bootstrap v4 with the new flexbox and grid system.

**Copying from the question I linked above, I am basically trying to achieve this:**

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               |                                             Search Input Form |
|  SITE LOGO    |---------------------------------------------------------------+
|               |                             Nav-B-1  Nav-B-2 Nav-B-3 Nav-B-4  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Nav-C-1        Nav-C-2         Nav-C-3        Nav-C-4       Nav-C-5      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                           ------Begin Body Content------
                           |                            |
                           V                            V
```

And then, IF POSSIBLE, I would love to shrink the main navigation back into a single navbar on mobile and tablet, while combining all of the menus EXCEPT the search together in one hamburger menu. To be honest, I thought I was lost on the first part of this question, but this second part has me even more flustered.

**Collapsed Navigation (Mobile and Tablet)**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SITE LOGO |                                                  Hamburger Menu     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                     Search Input Form     Search Button                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Expanded Navigation (Mobile and Tablet)**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SITE LOGO |                                                  Hamburger Menu     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Nav-B-1                                                                        |
|  Nav-B-2                                                                        |
|  Nav-B-3                                                                        |
|  Nav-B-4                                                                        |
|   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------   |
|  Nav-C-1                                                                        |
|  Nav-C-2                                                                        |
|  Nav-C-3                                                                        |
|  Nav-C-4                                                                        |
|  Nav-C-5                                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

---End Expanded Menu---

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                     Search Input Form     Search Button                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is this even possible? I'm wondering if Bootstrap isn't the right framework for something like this :(

Thank you in advance for the help!!!

**Here's what I've got so far:**

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
 .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
 }
}
 
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
 }
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 nav#hide-on-mobile {
   visibility: hidden;
   clear: both;
   display: none;
 }
 }
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav id="hide-on-mobile" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light flex-row pb-0 pt-3">
        <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light flex-row">
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                sandbox
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler ml-lg-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent, #navbarSupportedContent2" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
         </div>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark py-0">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It'll be more complex to combine the two seperate navbars to  have a unified logo, But why use two navbars in the first place? You can make a single container and align the search and bottom nav in that itself and thus, you can manage the logo with the span of the two navbars without much problems.

Comment: I didn’t even think of this! Still relatively new to web dev :) I’m gonna try to brainstorm how to implement this, I’ll post here if I figure it out!! Huge thank you

Comment: No problem and good luck :)

Comment: This is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635126/bootstrap-4-navbar-with-2-rows/42635243