# bootstrap 5 nav with 2 rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to make a fixed navbar on top with 2 rows not just one . the code i have is :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top red-900 bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

now the result is :
[image]

now i want to make 2 red rows . is there any clean way to do this ??

Comment: It's not clear which portions you want to be in 2 rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add `<nav>.....</nav>` agian after your first one to do this, check solution at this it may help [Bootstrap navbar with two rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112363/bootstrap-navbar-with-two-rows).